# Fallo consulta a base de datos

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

estoy intentando hacer una consulta a una base de datos de coches y no me funciona, la función donde hago la consulta es esta:

```
public static ArrayList<Coche> filtradoAnuncios(String valor_marca, String valor_modelo, String valor_anyoDesde, String valor_anyoHasta, String valor_puertas, String valor_cambio, String valor_precioDesde, String valor_precioHasta, String valor_kilometros, String valor_potencia, String valor_combustible) {

    //Marca
    if(valor_marca.equals("Cualquiera")) {
        valor_marca = "";
    }

    //Modelo
    if(valor_modelo.equals("Cualquiera")) {
        valor_modelo = "";
    }

    //Puertas
    if(valor_puertas.equals("Cualquiera")) {
        valor_puertas = "";
    }

    //Cambio
    if(valor_cambio.equals("Cualquiera")) {
        valor_cambio = "";
    }

    //Combustible
    if(valor_combustible.equals("Cualquiera")) {
        valor_combustible = "";
    }

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM anuncio_coches WHERE marca LIKE ? AND modelo LIKE ? AND anyo between ? and ? AND precio between ? and ? AND kilometros between ? AND potencia between ? AND puertas LIKE ? AND combustible LIKE ? AND cambio LIKE ?";
    ArrayList<Coche> listaBusqueda = new ArrayList<>();

    String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM anuncio_coches WHERE marca LIKE '%" + valor_marca + "%' AND modelo LIKE '%" + valor_modelo + "%' AND anyo between " + valor_anyoDesde + " and " + valor_anyoHasta + " AND precio between  " + valor_precioDesde + " and " + valor_precioHasta + " AND kilometros between " + valor_kilometros + " AND potencia between " + valor_potencia + " AND puertas LIKE '%"+ valor_puertas+"%' AND combustible LIKE '%" + valor_combustible + "%' AND cambio LIKE '%" + valor_cambio + "%'";

    try(PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);){ 
        ps.setString(1, "'%" + valor_marca + "%'");
        ps.setString(2, "'%" + valor_modelo + "%'");
        ps.setString(3, valor_anyoDesde);
        ps.setString(4, valor_anyoHasta);
        ps.setString(5, valor_precioDesde);
        ps.setString(6, valor_precioHasta);
        ps.setString(7, valor_kilometros);
        ps.setString(8, valor_potencia);
        ps.setString(9, "'%" + valor_puertas + "%'");
        ps.setString(10, "'%" + valor_combustible + "%'");
        ps.setString(11, "'%" + valor_cambio + "%'");
        ps.execute();
        ResultSet rs = ps.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()) {
            String marca = rs.getString("marca");
            String modelo = rs.getString("modelo");
            int anyo = rs.getInt("anyo");
            int precio = rs.getInt("precio");
            int kilometros = rs.getInt("kilometros");
            int potencia = rs.getInt("potencia");
            int puertas = rs.getInt("puertas");
            String combustible = rs.getString("combustible");
            Double consumo = rs.getDouble("consumo");
            String cambio = rs.getString("cambio");
            String color = rs.getString("color");
            listaBusqueda.add(new Coche(marca, modelo, precio, anyo, kilometros, potencia, puertas, combustible, consumo, cambio, color));
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("no funciona");
    }
    return listaBusqueda;
}
```

No se porque no funciona, he hecho una consulta fácil, y la String sql al final, cuando recoje los parámetros queda así:

> SELECT * FROM anuncio_coches WHERE marca LIKE '%%' AND modelo LIKE '%%' AND anyo between 1980 and 2018 AND precio between 0 and 1000000 AND kilometros between 0 and 1000000 AND potencia between 0 and 10000 AND puertas LIKE '%%' AND combustible LIKE '%%' AND cambio LIKE '%%'

Pongo esta consulta en MySQLWorkbench y me funciona.Me debería salir los registros de los todos coches que tengo en la base de datos pero no lo hace, espero que me ayudéis, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El problema son las comillas simples, que no tienes que añadirlas antes de los `%` (cuando usas `ps.setString(...)` ya se asume que es un texto y que al generarse la consulta tendrá que usarlas)

```
try(PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);){ 
        ps.setString(1, "%" + valor_marca + "%");
        ps.setString(2, "%" + valor_modelo + "%");
        ps.setString(3, valor_anyoDesde);
        ps.setString(4, valor_anyoHasta);
        ps.setString(5, valor_precioDesde);
        ps.setString(6, valor_precioHasta);
        ps.setString(7, valor_kilometros);
        ps.setString(8, valor_potencia);
        ps.setString(9, "%" + valor_puertas + "%");
        ps.setString(10, "%" + valor_combustible + "%");
        ps.setString(11, "%" + valor_cambio + "%");

...
}
```

Comment: Eso es lo que tenía antes, aun así he vuelto a probar, y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: No sé si es una errata que sólo está en la pregunta, pero en el código pone `... AND kilometros between ? AND potencia between ? AND puertas LIKE ?`... faltan parámetros en los between

Comment: no, como puede ver en la consulta entera, los parámetros recibidos son los correctos. En cada between le paso dos valores

Comment: Ok, es por ir descartando cosas... ¿has probado a imprimir en consola `ps.toString()`?

Answer (score 0):

En el String sql indicas que se espera recibir 11 parametros y al objeto ps del tipo PreparedStatement efectivamente le mandas 11 parametros, ahora bien, analizemos el objeto sql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM anuncio_coches 
WHERE marca LIKE ? 
    AND modelo LIKE ? 
    AND anyo between ? and ? 
    AND precio between ? and ? 
    AND kilometros between ? 
    AND potencia between ? 
    AND puertas LIKE ? 
    AND combustible LIKE ? 
    AND cambio LIKE ?;
```

Como conclusión se tiene, que los objetos sql y sql1 tienen la consulta mal creada, curiosamente luego indicas como queda la consulta y esa esta bien, aquí mi recomendación es tener acomodado el código y solicitar ayuda si se requiere.